# Изменить текст меню по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят все привет. У меня есть кнопка, которая создает меню. Перед созданием меню, я могу выбрать количество пунктов в этом меню. После создания, меню появляется на странице. Дальше по клику на это меню, я могу поменять это меню. И я хочу добавить textarea, которая будет менять текст. Например я выбрал 6 пунктов в меню, у меня в настройках появится 6 textarea и каждая textarea будет отвечать за свой пункт. Помогите мне пожалуйста

```js
$(".btn-insert-txt").on('click', function() {
  var count = $(".select-menu-count").val();
    var align = $(".form-menu-align").val();
    var float = "text-align:";
  var border = "border:none;"
    var editBlock = "$('.edit-block')";
    var display = ",'block'";
    var closeTag = ";";
  var ulClass = "menu";
  var flex = "display:flex";
  var onclick = "onclick='editMenu()'";
  var justifyContent = "justify-content:"+align+"";

  var ul = $("<ul class=" + ulClass + " style=" + flex + closeTag + justifyContent + "></ul>");
  var menu = "<li><a class='link-" + align + "' " + onclick + " style=" + float + align + closeTag + border + ">text</a></li>";
  for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    ul.append(menu);
  }
  $(".preview").append(ul);
}); 

function editMenu() {
  $('.edit-menu').show();
}
```

```css
.edit-menu {
  background: #272822;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: right;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
   display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal-menu-container">
<div class="modal-insert-txt">
<div class="header-modal">
<h2>Добавить</h2>
<span class="close-modal" onclick="closeModalMenu()"></span>
</div>
<hr>
          <span>Количество ссылок</span>
           <div class="form-group">
          <select class="select-menu-count">
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
          <span>Выравнивание</span>
          <div class="form-group">  
          <select class="form-menu-align">
            <option value="left">Слева</option>
            <option value="center">По центру</option>
            <option value="right">Справа</option>
          </select>
        </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn-insert-txt">Вставить текст</button>
      </div>
      </div>
        </div>
       
  <div class="edit-menu">
    <span>Изменить текст</span>
    Первый текст: <textarea name="first" id="first" cols="10" rows="1"></textarea>
    Второй текст: <textarea name="second" id="second" cols="10" rows="1"></textarea>
  </div>
  
        <div class="preview">


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".btn-insert-txt").on('click', function() {
  var count = $(".select-menu-count").val(),
      align = $(".form-menu-align").val(),
      ulMenu = $("<ul>",{
        class: `menu ${align}`
      });
  
  for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    let liMenuItem = $("<li>", {
        text: `text-${i}`
    });
    ulMenu.append(liMenuItem);
  }
  $(".preview").append(ulMenu);
}); 

var menu = null;
$("body").on("click", "ul.menu li", function(e){
  menu = $(this).parent(".menu");
  
  let editBlock = $(".edit-menu"),
      count = menu.find("li").length,
      inputs = editBlock.children(".edit-menu_inputs");

  editBlock.children(".edit-menu_inputs").empty();
  
  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
    let editInput = $("<input>", {
        value: menu.children("li").eq(i).text()
    });
    inputs.append(editInput);
  } 
  
  editBlock.show();
});

$("body").on("change keyup", ".edit-menu_inputs input", function(e){
  let index = $(".edit-menu_inputs input").index($(this));
  
  menu.find("li").eq(index).text($(this).val());
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  
}

.left{
   align-items: flex-start;
}
.center{
   align-items: center;
}
.right{
   align-items: flex-end;
}

.edit-menu {
  background: #272822;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: right;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
   display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>

  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal-menu-container">
<div class="modal-insert-txt">
<div class="header-modal">
<h2>Добавить</h2>
<span class="close-modal" onclick="closeModalMenu()"></span>
</div>
<hr>
          <span>Количество ссылок</span>
           <div class="form-group">
          <select class="select-menu-count">
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
          <span>Выравнивание</span>
          <div class="form-group">  
          <select class="form-menu-align">
            <option value="left">Слева</option>
            <option value="center">По центру</option>
            <option value="right">Справа</option>
          </select>
        </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn-insert-txt">Вставить текст</button>
      </div>
      </div>
        </div>
       
  <div class="edit-menu">
    <span>Изменить текст</span>
    <div class='edit-menu_inputs'>
    </div>
  </div>
  
        <div class="preview">


</div>
</body>
</html>
  
</body>
</html>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```